# user name and password popup coming for windows authentication in IIS

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, web-hosting, iis-10

**Details**: I have hosted internal application on IIS 10. One of functionality requirement is open the one of the form to external users (out of our organization). To achieve this, DNS entry done with internal IP and external IP. I have bind internal IP with DNS name in IIS. This application work on SSO so no user creadtianls required to login to application. “Windows Authentication” configure in IIS

**Problem**: Username and password pop up comes when try to run the application when VPN is connected (within organization)

**Note**: We have done similar functionality many times, but first time stuck on this issue for long time. This time difference is hosted it on new dedicated VM

Comment: Ask your domain/network administrators to troubleshoot. This is not a programming question.